# spring-integration : switch on failover to IBM MQ queue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq

We have a situation where we need to implement functionality to handle below scenarios(using IBM MQ and Spring Integration):

1. If a JMS queue fails intraday application should auto connect to another defined queue without loss of messages.
2. Dynamically alter a queue configuration when the application is running, or even if we need to restart any unsent messages should not be lost.

Kindly provide your view on how to implement a good design for handling these scenarios as we are new to using spring integration.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare one more JMS Outbound Channel Adapter for that second queue and have it as a second subscriber (with `order=2`) to the same direct channel. That channel must be configured with `load-balancer="none"`. This way if first handler fails to process message, it will be delivered to the second subscriber and so on.

Comment: Thanks we are in the process of testing this scenarios with multiple queues. But can you tell if spring will revert permanently to use second queue (after it encounters an error on 1st queue) or will keep checking each transaction (in case first queue comes back up ) and reverts back to it?

Comment: Yes, it always tries the first subscriber and goes to second only if that fails

Comment: So I think it will add a delay for each message while trying to check both subscribers in order ? Please correct me if I understood wrong...but our application has multiple queues and quite heavy traffic so performance is a very important criteria. It will be better if we can configure when it should re-validate the subscriber list, or just keep using the one which works.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a delay on each message to try each subscriber. If you need more sophisticated solution, you should think more and involve many components including scheduling to check availability periodically. The router in that case may decide where to go depending of the state provided by the scheduled task